# Equal to operation not working with timestamp column postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

Trying to run following query,

`select * from "Activities" where "CreatedDateTime" = '2020-04-01 05:52:59'::timestamp;`

where CreatedDateTime type is **timestamp**

Comment: A timestamp has microsecond precision, your value that you are comparing doesn't specify them.

Comment: I'm Storing value **now()** for this column.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. It might have stored `2020-04-01 05:52:59.768` and you are comparing that to `2020-04-01 05:52:59.000`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

As was already suggested, the most likely cause is that the stored timestamps have microsecond data while your query does not:

```
2020-04-01 05:52:59.128256 != 2020-04-01 05:52:59
```

To get around this you can use an interval for comparison as in:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "Activities"
    WHERE "CreatedDateTime" >= '2020-04-01 05:52:59'
        AND "CreatedDateTime" < '2020-04-01 05:53:00';
```

You haven't specified a programming language but if you're using one, adding a second to an existing **timestamp** or **datetime** object should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fractions of a second.  One solution is:

```
date_trunc('second', "CreatedDateTime") = '2020-04-01 05:52:59'::timestamp
```

However, I don't recommend this because it cannot use indexes.  Instead:

```
"CreatedDateTime" >= '2020-04-01 05:52:59'::timestamp and
"CreatedDateTime" < '2020-04-01 05:52:59'::timestamp + interval '1 second'
```

Note:  This assumes that you want "truncation" for the match.  If you want rounding:

```
"CreatedDateTime" >= '2020-04-01 05:52:59'::timestamp - 0.5 * interval '1 second' and
"CreatedDateTime" < '2020-04-01 05:52:59'::timestamp + 0.5 * interval '1 second'
```